# circle with filling color slowly in android

Tags: android, android-animation, geometry

[image]

I want to show transparent color circle first and it should fill one color in that circle slowly. I tried by using circle progress bar but i didnt get the proper result. Any one help me to reach this output like this picture.

Comment: [Refer this similar code.](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)

Answer (score 4):

Try this piece of code to create a circle with filling color. pass it integer value to draw how many percent of filling area. :)

```
private void circularImageBar(ImageView iv2, int i) {

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b); 
    Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#c4c4c4"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 140, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDB4C"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);   
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        final RectF oval = new RectF();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        oval.set(10,10,290,290);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, ((i*360)/100), false, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);    
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8E8E93")); 
        paint.setTextSize(140);
        canvas.drawText(""+i, 150, 150+(paint.getTextSize()/3), paint); 
        iv2.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```